# How to update reference argument in functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, pass-by-reference

If I have two functions, both with arguments that include a reference to a string. One function will call the other, but both functions could have the ability to set value of the referenced variable.

Currently, the below code will keep the variable as `NULL` instead of updating the variable. I know for sure that reason is being set, because I can breakpoint where it's setting reason (and even output reason in the current scope).

```
function function_a(string $path, ?string &$reason = null): ?string {
    // Set to false for example purposes
    $checkIsValid = false;
    if(!$checkIsValid) {
        $reason = 'Reason why it is invalid';

        return null;
    }

    return function_b($path, $reason);
}

function function_b(string $path, ?string &$reason = null): ?string {
    $anotherValidCheck = false;
    if($anotherValidCheck) {
        $reason = 'Another reason why it is invalid';

        return null;
    }

    return 'Some value';
}
```

There's also core PHP function that's using similar functionality to what I'm attempting to achieve ([output argument in the `exec` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)). Another example is the `out` keyword in .NET. I'm guessing since PHP references aren't quite like your typical reference, that this won't work?

Comment: I don't get it, this seems to work as expected. If I instantiate a string variable and pass it as the second argument of `function_a`, its value is indeed changed to `'Reason why it is invalid'` in the scope I called the function in.

Comment: Hmm you seem to be right, in a sandbox it works but in my local it doesn't. I must be missing something silly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I hadn't specified in my original question, I am using Laravel facades. For some reason, using a reference how I wanted didn't work with the Facade. Perhaps because of how it's overridding `__call` with the `Macroable` trait.

Using DI to use the repository class instead of the facade fixed the issue for me.

Anyway, hopefully this might help anyone else that comes across this issue.